# How to find out the occurred exception during using a PrintStream in Java

Tags: java, printwriter, printstream

I have just read, that in Java the classes `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter` don't throw checked exceptions. Instead they are using a kind of an error flag which I can read invoking the method `boolean checkError()` ([API link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#checkError--)).

Now, I am asking myself how to find out the reason why the exception occurred. The information that there was an exception is sometimes maybe not enough, or?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Based on the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/6af596144294/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l600), it looks like they discard the exception. All of the catch blocks look like this:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (IOException x) {
    trouble = true; // (x is ignored)
}
```

So the most straightforward solution is probably to not use `PrintStream`, if possible.

One workaround could be to extend `PrintStream` and wrap the output in another `OutputStream` which captures the exception before `PrintStream` catches (and discards) it. Something like this:

```
package mcve.util;

import java.io.*;

public class PrintStreamEx extends PrintStream {
    public PrintStreamEx(OutputStream out) {
        super(new HelperOutputStream(out));
    }

    /**
     * @return the last IOException thrown by the output,
     *         or null if there isn't one
     */
    public IOException getLastException() {
        return ((HelperOutputStream) out).lastException;
    }

    @Override
    protected void clearError() {
        super.clearError();
        ((HelperOutputStream) out).setLastException(null);
    }

    private static class HelperOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
        private IOException lastException;

        private HelperOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
            super(out);
        }

        private IOException setLastException(IOException e) {
            return (lastException = e);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            try {
                super.write(b);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw setLastException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            try {
                super.write(b);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw setLastException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            try {
                super.write(b, off, len);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw setLastException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            try {
                super.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw setLastException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            try {
                super.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw setLastException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```